# Declaring collections in C#

Tags: c#, collections

My question is: What is the most efficient and correct, for large set of data ?

```
 _pointBuffer1 = new Point3DCollection {  
            new Point3D(140.961, 142.064, 109.300), new Point3D(142.728, 255.678, (...)
```

-- or --

```
_pointBuffer1.Add(new Point3D(140.961, 142.064, 109.300)); _poitBuffer1.Add(142.728, (...)
```

Or is it the same ?

Point3D is declared as a Point3DCollection, but my question is for any object collection (could be Int32 for example) ..

Comment: You should strive to write complete code, unless your question is about syntax problems. In this case, you have "poit", an Add call with just the values, nested add calls (the second example doesn't close the call). But most importantly, you're missing the actual construction of the collection, ie. "_pointBuffer1 = new Point3DCollection();" so no, even if we disregard the syntax problems, they're not the same.

Comment: I have a class Models which constructs this point3DCollection first. The code I've present is on a InitMesh method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are compiled to the same IL. Collection initializers are just syntactic sugar. They will call the `Add` method. Example:

```
var res = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

is compiled to:

```
List<int> <>g__initLocal0 = new List<int>();
<>g__initLocal0.Add(1);
<>g__initLocal0.Add(2);
<>g__initLocal0.Add(3);
List<int> res = <>g__initLocal0;
```

The only difference is an additional local variable being declared.

Comment: Hm .. I see .. and what is the most correct in code design and documentation ?

Comment: Both are correct. It is up to you to decide what makes your code more readable.

Comment: You can choose whatever your personal coding guidelines saying. The only thing i would do, is to write every `new Point3D()` or `buffer.Add()` on a new line, so that you got a complete list in code.

Comment: Yes, it would be more correct, but I have ~150 points for this model and many many triangle indices (Int32), and texture coords :/ it would be a huge file. and there are other models too

Comment: @jose: It sounds like you shouldn't have that data in your source code then. That's what resource files are for...

Answer (score 7):

I would strongly suggest using the collection initializer for the sake of clarity (although I'd use some newlines as well).

They don't *quite* end up as the same IL, mind you. The first ends up being equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new Point3DCollection();
tmp.Add(new Point3D(140.961, 142.064, 109.300));
tmp.Add(new Point3D(142.728, 255.678));
...
_pointBuffer1 = tmp;
```

In other words, the assignment to the eventual variable is only made *after* all the `Add` calls.

This is important if your `Point3D` constructor somehow references `_pointBuffer1`!

Comment: +1 - Anyone that makes a recommendation *for the sake of clarity* deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Collection initialisation is syntactic sugar. By this I mean that it is a convenient shorthand that is understood by the complier. The compiler will produce code that is logically identical to calling the collection's add method for each element.

Comment: I would say that it is clearer to use collection initialisation as your intent is obvious (i.e. you are initialising the collection).